# Blender shuts down when rendering.

Tags: rendering

Gonna make it brief. Every time I try to render a specificscene, the software crashes (shuts down with no pop up or anything, it shuts down one second after I click render). As for others blend files, the rendering goes smooth and fine.

GPU I'm using: GeForce 920M.
Download link: http://www.mediafire.com/file/20i72axrfqctyd0/tut11_%282%29.blend

Comment: Your are probably biting more than you (your hardware) can chew, the scene is likely too heavy for that card and crashes Blender, or at best it is a bug and should be reported to the bug tracker. Adjust your scene to match your hardware capabilities.

Comment: In the future instead of "making it brief", add a detailed description of the scene you are dealing with, so that the answer does not depend exclusively on downloading a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have Subdivision cranked up to level 10 on ***two*** different objects.  It's causing your memory to fill up and crash the process.  Just set it to a reasonable number like 2.

[image]

From the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html?highlight=subdivision#performance-considerations):

> Performance Considerations:
>
> Higher levels of subdivisions mean more vertices, and more vertices means more memory will be used (both video memory for display (VRAM), and system RAM for rendering). Blender could potentially crash or hang if you do not have enough memory.

Comment: Oh, that's the problem. Thank you for clearing that out, must've increased it by mistake when I was tweaking others settings. Appreciate the fact response, thank you.

Comment: @BouzaziWessim - Hey, no problem at all.  With subdivision, each step is an order of magnitude.  I.e. it increases exponentially.  So a big difference can be seen even even with small numbers.  *Smooth* shading takes care of a lot of the visual smoothing anyway.